# When i try to publish a website wtih visual studio 2013 via FTP visual studio crashes

Tags: ftp, web, visual-studio-2013, publish

i'm having trouble publishing my website in visual studio 2013 itself. I've installed the latest version of visual studio and the latest version of vswebessentials. I love working on websites in visual studio but it would be easier if i could publish it within visual studio. I'm trying to publish it via the publish web menu to ftp visual studio stops and restarts. It happens when i've entered all the information needed for the ftp connection wehn i push the validate connection button or the publish button. I would like to make it work but i can't find the solution on the internet yet. I would be really gratefull for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve is on the right track. It seems that previously you only needed to supply the IP or domain of the FTP server and Visual Studio knew what to do. Somewhere along the line it must have forgot!

Here is a blog post detailing the issue and how to fix it:
[FTP Publish Visual Studio Crash](http://w3rdofmouth.com/post/84139521525/ftp-publish-visual-studio-crash)

TL;DR = Make sure the value you use for "Server:" begins with "ftp://"

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well, and the solution for me was to change the publish URL in the pubxml file from:

ftp.mysite.com

to

ftp://ftp.mysite.com

Comment: @BhavinNattar Stop robo-reviewing, look at it again. :P